# Dimension too large with pgfkeysvalueof

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is a bit silly example to get to the bottom of one problem.  I get error

```
Dimension too large
I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
```

Despite the highest value is only about 60pt.  What is wrong?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=between positions 0 and \pgfdecoratedpathlength step 10pt with {
  \node {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/distance from start}};}}}]
  (-1.4,-0.9) -- (-1.05,-0.9) arc (-90:0:0.20) -- (-0.85,0.7) arc (180:0:0.10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: After additional inspection, it seems that `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/distance from start}` fails if it stumbles on arc with very small radius.  Sounds rediculous, but...

Comment: Your path is too short. Use `(-14,-9) -- (-10.5,-9) arc (-90:0:2) -- (-8.5,7) arc (180:0:1)` instead.

Comment: @Symbol1 Interesting, but for shorter paths there is also no error, for example using `(-1.4,-0.9) -- (-1.05,-0.9) arc (-90:0:0.20) -- (-0.85,0.7)` is also fine.  Makes no sense.  There must be something more vicious problematic here.

Comment: Why ridiculous? It's TeX arithmetic.

Comment: @percusse So it is essentially a bug.  A possible workaround is `\begin{scope}[transform canvas={scale=0.5},scale=2]`, do you have any better?

Comment: It isn't a bug. It is a limitation of TeX, which cannot deal with dimensions greater than the limit. Given how these things work, this also means dimensions smaller than the corresponding limit. (No bigger than 19' and no smaller than 1/19', say.) This is hard-coded in TeX. Nothing to do with PGF/Ti*k*Z.

Comment: You can use fixed point or floating point. Note the disadvantages of canvas transformations noted in the manual.

Comment: @cfr As I have written it has nothing to do with the limits.  It only fails on small arcs.  Before and after small arcs (larger and smaller numbers) it is fine.

Comment: But the arcs require calculations involving numbers which exceed the limits. I'm not talking about the numbers visible in your explicit code, but the numbers implicitly required to execute it ;).

Answer (score 1):

Schrödinger's cat had the idea to use `\tikzset` to be able to locally install a modification of `veclen`. I do the calculations with `xfp` in order to avoid calculation errors (TeX limitation). This option is part of tkz-base  and tkz-euclide

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xfp]

    \draw[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=between positions 0 and \pgfdecoratedpathlength step 10pt with {
  \node {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/distance from start}};}}}]
      (-1.4,-0.9) -- (-1.05,-0.9) arc (-90:0:0.20) -- (-0.85,0.7) arc (180:0:0.10);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]